# Number of elements as compound

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cipher, chemistry

What simple compound is precious to life and encodes the total number of elements?

What other thing does it code and is revered by some as precious to life?

Accepted solution should show how the second thing refers to the first.

Comment: Is the answer a word?

Comment: @Stevo I think you'd have to be more specific, explain how that answers both questions, and its relation to chemistry.

Comment: I'd guess the reason they asked is that, if the answer is a single word, you're supposed to use the [word] tag

Comment: More elements will be isolated eventually, then this puzzle will be less answerable.

Comment: @bobble The table of elements is complete. You can make your criticism when you can demonstrate extra elements have been found.

Comment: @bobble — The latest few elements are pretty iffy anyway; they take a tremendous amount of energy to be created artificially, then they decay away completely within seconds. Who's going to going to spend so much money building another giant machine to create a tiny unstable atom of a "new element" that just messes up nice looking table? (I know someone probably will eventually)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> water
>  H2O

which is a simple chemical compound that is precious to life.

---

Converting to numbers:

> H-H-O
>  1-1-8 *(element #1 is hydrogen, and #8 is oxygen)*
>  one hundred and eighteen

this is the total number of elements.

---

With some poetic licence, this number could be said to encode:

> one one ate
>  one [object] [that] one [subject] ate
>  i.e. diet

which is also precious to life, and to be revered.

Comment: This does not answer the second part of the question: "What other thing does it code..."

Comment: Also, the first part asks for the compound, not the number of elements. Your answer has this in reverse, but otherwise appears to be correct.

Comment: @DanielMathias I've flipped my answer around as you suggested, but I'm still having some trouble with the way the question (and title) is phrased; it seems a bit clumsy.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I think I agree, it could be worded better, but when you get the answer that might shed a clearer light on the matter.

Comment: Good but partial answer. What else does it code?

Comment: @David — I've added to my answer, but I'm not sure it's what you're looking for

Comment: 'one one ate' is awesome but I guess wrong. Stab in the dark... Maybe 1 + 18 = A+R = air? Like water, it's precious to life. Not sure if it's revered... maybe as it relates to qi or by certain cultures.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a guess that might answer the second part of the question:

> The environment. Water is an essential part of our environment and, as we all know, a healthy natural environment is precious to life.

Comment: Good, but I think that's really the first answer. There's more to understand here.